# Setting a test-wide tolerance with BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

Within a `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE`, you can set a tolerance for all `BOOST_TEST` calls like so:

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(Testname, SomeFixture, *utf::tolerance(.01))
```

However, I cannot find a way to make this work with `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F`.

From Boost:

```
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F(my_fixture, test_case_name, dataset, var1, var2..., varN)
```

I've tried the obvious

```
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F(my_fixture, test_case_name, dataset, var1, var2..., varN, *utf::tolerance(.01))
```

but to no avail. It seems to me like it's just not supported.

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to replicate similar behavior** without having to specify a tolerance within every single `BOOST_TEST` call within a `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F`?

I am using version 1.72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to do that, but you can set the tolerance in a BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(), and you can have as many of those suites as you want.  So:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(suite1, *utf::tolerance(.01))
    BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F(my_fixture, test_case_name, dataset, var1, var2..., varN)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Interesting. This is promising, and I will probably accept this since it answers my original question. I do have a follow-on question: If I have multiple `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_Fs` that I want a different level of tolerance for each, using your above method I would have to have a separate test suite for each one? Could I maybe have a top-level suite and then nest each of those suites inside of it?

Comment: You can nest test suites.  You can also have multiple test suites, nested or not, within a single file or test executable.